# Установил JavaFX по инструкции. Не отображает границу и фоновый цвет окна

Tags: java, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();

        Text text = new Text("Hello from JavaFX!");
        text.setLayoutY(200);        
        text.setLayoutX(100);  

        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        root.getChildren().add(text);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```

P.S. Также заметил, что не меняется фоновый цвет окна

Comment: вы не добавили Text в какую либо панельку( в данном случае на stackPane) -поэтому текст не виден. про какую границу идет речь я так и не понял

Comment: Добавил, заработало. Теперь про границу. Разве у окна не должно быть панельки, где я могу свернуть или закрыть его?